# How can I get the right numpy working for python 3 in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, python-3.x, numpy

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and it has python 3 installed in default. I have installed numpy and scipy for python 3 using the Ubuntu package manager but not pip:

```
apt-get install python3-numpy python3-scipy
```

When I run a script with python3, it seems that it used the numpy installed with python 2.7:

```
python3 script.py
Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
line 18, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 170, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct
```

I do not want to mess up python2.7 and python3 and those corresponding numpy and scipy. How do I set the pointer that python3 uses its numpy given the way I installed numpy for python3?

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with multiple versions of python on the same machine can be tricky. Most will recommend that you to use virtual environments. But a quick fix is to just append the python version you want to pip like so:

```
pip3 install numpy scipy
```

This will install packages globally.

Reference :
[pip: dealing with multiple Python versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions)